# Javascript variable scope & sharing content between files

Tags: javascript

A common question that I am struggling to make work -

**Task:**

Keyboard actions served to different pieces of my page

- **index.html** using "*<body onkeydown="onkeydown_resp()">*"
- onkeydown_resp() is in *utils.js*
- page is hosting an iframe with *projects.html*
- uses keyboard to stop/start some media

**Need:**

JavaScript state changes shared across Js & HTML content

e.g. *onkeydown_resp*() may -

- Trigger the loaded iframe of projects.html to toggle to a new project (*Key1*)
- Stop an animation for one of those project demos (*Key2*)
- And toggle some audio (*Key3*)

I have tried a plethora of options to no success. I am just looking to learn & establish a portfolio demo for [www.justinreina.com](http://www.justinreina.com).

**Question:**

- How can I get this task to work?

Expected - create a global 'var' or window.myVar and share it

Tried - None of these seem to work [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932782/global-variables-in-javascript-across-multiple-files)/[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476426/how-do-i-share-a-global-variable-between-multiple-files?rq=1)/[3](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/global-variable)/[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500808/sharing-variables-between-js-files-in-separate-folders-locations)/[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553614/share-javascript-variable-between-files)/[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585558/how-to-share-a-variable-between-two-files-generated-by-a-function)/[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366524/sharing-variables-between-files-without-globals)

Comment: It seems your question is about interacting with the iframe, but none of the linked Q&A say a thing about iframes. Perhaps you should search for "sharing state with iframe"?

Comment: This may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#scripting

Comment: You might want to check [out namespacing too](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-javascript-design/9781449334840/ch13s15.html). We don't tend to use it too much these days, but it was very useful.

Comment: An iFrame is a separate document and does not have access to any of the properties defined on the parent window object. Use cross messaging as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9154267/12291657

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to communicate between iframe and the parent site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)

Comment: you guys are amazing, thank you. I am learning much here I will process this and get back to you (wow - did not expect this!)